# Particle system to add boils

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes

Hello blender stack exchange.

I'm trying to make a character look progressively more sick by having boils pop up on the skin.
They dont shrink, or grow, they just pop up.

However, i see that in the particle system i can not keyframe the number of emissions.
This leaves me stumped on how to control the amount of boils over time.
Any tips or methods that allow for the random placement of objects on a mesh to pop up?
Or am i in the right direction but the wrong settings.

It's basically the sprinkles part from the blender guru donut tutorial.

Thanks in advance!